# Concurrent bruteforce and memory overflow : the best of both worlds?

Tags: c++, concurrency, lazy-evaluation, brute-force, qtconcurrent

I'm working on a bruteforce algorithm for solving a kind of Puzzle.
That puzzle is a rectangle, and for some reasons irrelevant here, the number of possible solutions of a rectangle whose size is width*height is 2^(min(width, height)) instead of 2^(width*height).
Both dimensions can be considered as in range 1..50. (most often below 30 though)
This way, the numbers of solutions is, at worst, 2^50 (about 1 000 000 000 000 000 so). I store solution as an unsigned 64 bits number, a kind of "seed"

I have two working algortihms for bruteforce solving.
Assuming N is min(width, height) and isCorrect(uint64_t) a predicate that returns whether the solution with given seed is correct or not.

The most naive algorithm is roughly this :

```
vector<uint64_t> solutions;
for (uint64_t i = 0; i < (1 << N); ++i)
{
    if (isCorrect(i))
        solutions.push_back(i);
}
```

It works perfectly (assuming predicate is actually implemented :D) but does not profit from multiples cores, so I'd like to have a multi-threadead approach.
I've come across QtConcurrent, which gives concurrent filter and map functions, that automatically create optimal number of threads to share burden.

So I have a new algorithm that is roughly this :

```
vector<unit64_t> solutionsToTry;
solutionsToTry.reserve(1 << N);
for (uint64_t i = 0; i < (1 << N); ++i)
    solutionsToTry.push_back(i);
//Now, filtering
QFuture<unit64_t> solutions = QtConcurrent::filtered(solutionsToTry, &isCorrect);
```

It does work too, and a bit faster, but when N goes higher than 20, There's simply not enough room in my RAM to allocate the vecotr (with N = 20 and 64 bits numbes, I need 8,3 GB of RAM. It's okay with swap partitions etc, but sinces it gets multiplied by 2 every time N increases by 1, it can't go further)

Is there a simple way to have concurrent filtering without bloating memory ?

If there isn't, I might rather hand-split loops on 4 threads to get concurrency without optimal size, or write the algorithm in Haskell to get lazy-evaluation and filtering of infinite lists :-)

Comment: Not sure about the requirement of `Sequence` required by `QtConcurrent::filtered`, but it might be possible to use a "Counter iterator"-like.

Comment: As for avoiding std::vector memory doubling , I would look at its reserve method : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve Also as an alternative to QtConcurrent to utilise multiple cores , you can look at openMP ( integration would be relatively easy as MSVC and GCC has support with pragma directives ) Also you can try Intel TBB : https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-generic-parallel-algorithms I have used OpenMP in past as it was straightforward to add to existing code and helped, but I can not compare their performance as I did not benchmark